# Poner negrita en los system.out.println en java

Tags: java

quería saber si hay forma de poner unas palabras que estén dentro de un System.out.println(); en negrita u otro formato de texto.
EN JAVA

Comment: Mira esta publicacion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109678/java-print-in-bold

Answer (score 3):

En java se utilizan las denominadas secuencias de escape ANSI para cambiar el formato del texto , este formato `"\u001B[30m"` te debería funcionar aunque depende del IDE que utilices. En Eclipse por ejemplo no funcionan.

```
System.out.print("\u001B[30m"+ texto);
```